# Upgrading a MySQL database using numbered scripts compared to a version field

Tags: linux, mysql, bash

I have been given a task to upgrade a MySQL 5.7 DB using a directory of sequenced scripts and comparing them to a version field in a DB.

You should query the DB, then compare the returned table number to the scripts in the directory, and if the number is lower than the highest script - execute all scripts leading upto the highest. There may be gaps in the numbering of the scripts also

The question is also outlined here;
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214087/how-to-upgrade-a-mysql-database-using-numbered-scripts-based-on-a-version-field

However I have created a solution to the problem - except I am unable to get the scripts to execute in sequence. If there is a gap in the numbering my grep will pull another script that shares the same number instead - how can i avoid this?

i.e grep for 6 but it executes 66.update.sql instead of 6.update.sql

Note; I am also aware the if statement $CURRENT_DB_VERSION -lt 9 is probably redundant - but it was my attempt to try and resolve the issue of any script having a single integer preceeded by 0.

I did create a version of the script where i would just use the sort -n | head -1 function to execute the scripts in order and remove them once executed - but I couldnt get the script to start executing .sql scripts at the DB Version.

```
#!/bin/bash
####### Usage check 
[[ $# -ne 5 ]] && echo -e "Please provide the SQL scripts directory, username, hostname, database and password \nUSAGE: ./sql_upgrade.sh /directory username hostname dbname password" && exit

####### access / store db information
cd $1
user=$2
host=$3
database=$4
pass=$5

######## DB Version store
mysql -u $user -h $host -p$pass -D $database -e "SELECT version FROM versionTable" > dbvers.out
CURRENT_DB_VERSION=`cat dbvers.out | grep -o '[0-9]\+'`
highest_upgrade_version=`ls $(pwd) | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | sort -rn | head -n 1 | awk 'NR' |  sed 's/^0*//'`

######### create list of scripts and order them
ls $(pwd) | grep .sql | sort -n >> scripts_list.txt

while [[ $CURRENT_DB_VERSION -lt $highest_upgrade_version || $CURRENT_DB_VERSION -eq $highest_upgrade_version ]]
do
    next_script_to_execute=`grep -Eo $CURRENT_DB_VERSION scripts_list.txt | sort -n | head -n 1`        
    if [[ $next_script_to_execute -gt $CURRENT_DB_VERSION || -z $next_script_to_execute ]]
            then
        ((CURRENT_DB_VERSION++))
    elif [[ $CURRENT_DB_VERSION -lt 9 ]]
            then
        for i in $(ls $(pwd) | sort -n| grep -E "^[0]" | grep $CURRENT_DB_VERSION| head -1); 
                    do mysql -u $user -h $host -p$pass -D $database < $i
        echo $i "is currently being executed"
        ((CURRENT_DB_VERSION++))
                    done
    else
        for i in $(ls $(pwd) | sed 's/^[1-9]*\+ //' | grep -E $CURRENT_DB_VERSION | sort -n | head -n 1); do mysql -u $user -h $host -p$pass -D $database < $i
        ((CURRENT_DB_VERSION++))
                    echo $i "is currently being executed"
        done
            fi
done

((CURRENT_DB_VERSION--))
echo "Current version of the Database is: "$CURRENT_DB_VERSION
mysql -u $user -h $host -p$pass -D $database -e "UPDATE versionTable SET version = $CURRENT_DB_VERSION"

### cleanup temp files
rm -rf scripts_list.txt
rm -rf dbvers.out
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to re-invent something like [Liquibase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase) or [Flyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things.

Minimal example here for the logic you require:

```
CURRENT_DB_VERSION=5

for FILE in `ls -1 |sort -n`
do
  FILEVERSION=$(echo $FILE | sed -e 's:^0*::' | sed -e 's/[^0-9]*//g')
  echo "Filename: $FILE Version: $FILEVERSION"
  if (( $FILEVERSION > $CURRENT_DB_VERSION )); then
    echo "File $FILEVERSION is newer version than database $CURRENT_DB_VERSION"
    # execute the file here 
  else
    echo "File $FILEVERSION is older or same version as database version $CURRENT_DB_VERSION"
  fi

done
```

Comment: Thank you phil, I have adapted your comment into my solution and it works perfectly, with some minor tweaks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: parsing the output of ls is a bad idea. File names on Unix can have really bad characters in them and ls might rewrite parts of your filenames in ways you did not expect. I suggest to always use globbing instead.

Given that you know the version at which you start as $current_db_version and the version at which you want to stop as $target_db_version you can simply iterate over all the numbers and use a glob to determine the scripts to run for that specific version:

```
for ver in $(seq "${current_db_version}" "${target_db_version}"); do
  echo "Upgrading to ${ver}"
  for script in ./${ver}.*.sql; do
    echo "Executing ${script}"
    test -x "${script}" && "${script}"
  done
done
```